# Converting String to Date using Moment.js returning Invalid Date

Tags: node.js, mongoose, momentjs

I am trying to add date data into Mongoose in my Node server, and this comes from a form that sends the date as a string.  I have the following code:

```
    let ticket_data = req.body.ticket;
    console.log(ticket_data);
    ticket_data.due_date = moment(ticket_data.due_date, "MM-DD-YYYY").toDate(); 
    console.log(ticket_data.due_date);
```

The console.logs are returning:

```
{ ticket_name: 'Ticket Name',
  assigned_user: '5ec2b8b38b2508027f2f0c90',
  due_date: '21. 5. 2020',
  description: 'This is a test ticket' }
Invalid Date
```

I am unsure why I am getting back an invalid date, the formats seem to be correct. Is there a detail here I am missing?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying format inside `moment()` , the format that you receive so that moment will parse it to a valid date.

```js
let data = "21. 5. 2020";
let res = moment(data, "DD. M. YYYY"); // this will be valid moment date now
console.log(res.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```